# passing array variable to ajax cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to implement something like **[this](http://www.tkmaxx.com/men/view-all-mens-clothing/icat/2000#esp_cf=Size&esp_filter_Size=L)**  where a user can select multiple conditions to search. My approach is to populate an array with selected conditions and pass it via ajax to make a request. I have the following codes in my ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


  <?php 
        //$array = array();
        $array["a"] = "Foo";
        $array["b"] = "Bar";
        $array["c"] = "Baz";
        $array["d"] = "Wom"; 
        $y = serialize($array);
        //$str = 'Yomi';
    ?>

  var y = '<?php echo $y ; ?>';

  $('.elementtosort').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/elegante/weafe_length_prices/results/",
          data: y,
          cache: false,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'Html',
          success: function (data) {
              $('#context').html(data);
          }
 });
});
});
```

and in my action i am trying to debug what was passed but keep getting strange results after each tweak

```
     public function results(){
     if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
          debug($_REQUEST);
          $this->render('filtered','ajax');
     }


}
```

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't believe the `serialize` method is what you want to use here. Because you are dealing with JavaScript, you probably want to output as json. Something like `$y = json_encode($array);` would probably work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Please change from

```
$y = serialize($array);
```

to

```
$y = json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
$y = serialize($array);
```

to

```
$y = json_encode($array);
```

AND remove single quotes

```
var y = <?php echo $y ; ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks.I found a way round it by changing data: y to data: 'y='+y, in my ajax call.
Got back my array with  debug(unserialize($_REQUEST['y'])); in my controller action.